# How to include country-industry and industry-year fixed effects in R?

Tags: r, plm

For my master thesis, I want to analyze the impact of private equity (PE) investments on the industry performance in Latin America in the period 2009-2018. 
In the basic model specification, I will regress a PE dummy variable that indicates the occurrence of a PE investment in a given country-industry against different industry measures, including employment growth, profitability growth, etc. The database that I built contains 6 different countries, 9 industries and 10 years. (see picture)
[DataBase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvuF8.png)

Methodologically, I am following a recent work by Bernstein et al. (2017): Private Equity and Industry Performance, in which the authors estimate a fixed effect model to analyse the impact of PE investments. To control for common shocks between industries and countries, they include industry-year and country-industry fixed effects in their model specifications. The final regression of the fixed effect panel is as follows.

[Model Specification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRSlH.png)

The problem that I'm having is that I don't know how to include two different fixed effects at the same time in the plm function in R as it only allows for one individual and time fixed effect in the index.

I put below the code for the basic fixed effect model that I want to use. However, it always shows an error. I guess this is because there are several countries for a given industry and thus the indiviudal is not clearly defined. I also tried to include the categoric variable "countries" as a dummy in the model, however with the same error message. Thus, my main question is how I can include both fixed effects at the same time in the model (country-industry and industry-year).

**Used R Code:**

Employment Growth (1)

```
plm_empl = plm(empl ~ PE, data=DataSet_MasterThesis, index=c("industries", 
"years") , model = "within")
```

Employment Growth (2)

```
plm_empl = plm(empl ~ PE + countries, data=DataSet_MasterThesis, 
index=c("industries", "years") , model = "within")
```

**Error Message:**

```
Error in pdim.default(index[[1]], index[[2]]) : 
   duplicate couples (id-time)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In pdata.frame(data, index) :
   duplicate couples (id-time) in resulting pdata.frame
  to find out which, use e.g. table(index(your_pdataframe), useNA = "ifany")
2: In is.pbalanced.default(index[[1]], index[[2]]) :
  duplicate couples (id-time)
```

I would be very grateful for any kind of help with this problem.

Comment: It would help if you can show a bit of your data or provide an example. The error messages seem to say there is duplicated in the data.

Comment: The typical method is to make these factor variables and include them directly. The within estimator needs one observation per period, but throwing in dummies is more flexible in this regard. If you have tons of levels, then use the `lfe` package.

Comment: Also, the `interaction` function will easily produce factors variables for industry-region and industry-period for example. See `?interation` for more info.

Comment: @suren: you can find an example of the data in the photo that I posted in the question

Comment: @lmo: So you recommend just using the regular lm function with factor variables for countries, industries and years?

Comment: Or the `lfe` package. Either way, you should get the same point estimates. You can then cluster standard errors with `multivcov` or `clusterSE` packages.